# "if" statement Looping through twice when using data driven pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcgis, arcpy

I have a script which is designed to place inset maps onto specific pages while exporting Data Driven Pages, the script is amalgamation of a friend's work and some of my own code from other projects.

The issue is the code exports pages 15 and 16 twice one with my inset maps and the other without and I can't figure out why.

I think it is something to do with the indentation within the Loop but I cant get it so it behaves in any other way. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import arcpy, os, time, datetime
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
PageNumber = "Page " 

# Create an output directory variable i.e the location of your maps folder
outDir = r"C:\Users\support\Desktop\Python\Book of Reference"

# Create a new, empty pdf document in the specified output directory
# This will be your final product
finalpdf_filename = outDir + r"\FinalMapBook.pdf"
if os.path.exists(finalpdf_filename): # Check to see if file already exists, delete if it does
  os.remove(finalpdf_filename)
finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalpdf_filename)


# Create a Data Driven Pages object from the mxd you wish to export
mxdPath = r"C:\Users\support\Desktop\Python\Book Of Reference\Book_Of_Reference_20160526_Python_Test.mxd"
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages

# Create objects for the layout elements that will be moving, e.g., inset data frame, scale text
Page15 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap)[1]
Page16 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap)[2]  

# Instead of exporting all pages at once, you will need to use a loop to export one at a time  
# This allows you to check each index and execute code to add inset maps to the correct pages

for pgIndex in range(1, tempDDP.pageCount + 1, 1):

  # Create a name for the pdf file you will create for each page
  temp_filename = r"C:\Users\support\Desktop\Python\Book of Reference\Book of Reference" + \
                            str(pgIndex) + ".pdf"
  if os.path.exists(temp_filename):
    os.remove(temp_filename) #Removes pdf if it is already in the folder

  # Code for setting up the inset map on the first page #
  if (pgIndex == 15):
    # Set position of inset map to place it on the page layout
    Page15.elementPositionX = 20.1717
    Page15.elementPositionY = 2.0382
        # Set the desired size of the inset map for this page
    Page15.elementHeight = 9.7337
    Page15.elementWidth = 12.7115
        # Set the desired extent for the inset map
    Page15insetExtent = arcpy.Extent(518878,108329,519831,107599)    
    Page15insetExtent = Page15insetExtent
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "RANGE", pgIndex)
    finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename) 
    Page15.elementPositionX = 50 #Move the Inset back off the page 
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView() #Refresh to ensure the Inset has been removed 
    print PageNumber + str(pgIndex)


  if (pgIndex == 16):
        # Set up inset map
    Page16.elementPositionX = 2.1013
    Page16.elementPositionY = 18.1914
    Page16.elementHeight = 9.7337
    Page16.elementWidth = 12.7115
    Page16insetExtent = arcpy.Extent(520012, 107962, 521156,107086)
    Page16insetExtent = Page16insetExtent
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    print PageNumber + str(pgIndex)
    tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "RANGE", pgIndex)
    finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename)
    print PageNumber + str(pgIndex)
    Page16.elementPositionX = 50
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()



  # Else Fuction takes care of the pages that dont have insets and just itterates through using the loop on line 28
  else : 
    tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "RANGE", pgIndex)
    finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename)
    print PageNumber + str(pgIndex)

# Clean up
del tempMap

# Update the properties of the final pdf
finalPdf.updateDocProperties(pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS",
                             pdf_layout="SINGLE_PAGE")
# Save your result
finalPdf.saveAndClose()

end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: If you check [the site](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-a-map-book-with-inset-maps.htm) from where your code was copied, you'll see that the indentation is different. Try matching the indentation in the example under the heading "Writing an export script" by moving lines such as `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()`, `tempDDP.exportToPDF(...)`, etc. out of the `if` statements.

Comment: Moving the lines worked, it now runs perfectly. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that when the pgIndex is 15 it performs the export as intended. Then it checks if the pgIndex is 16. The pgIndex is not 16 so it drops into the `else` and re-exports without the inset maps. I would recommend changing the second if to an `elif`